# Insert element at the beginning of Ruby Hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a use-case where I have an existing hash:

```
response = { aa: 'aaa', bb: 'bbb' }
```

I need to add `id` as one of the keys.

When I use `response.merge(id: 'some_id')` and then convert it into JSON, I got `id` as the last element, which I don't want.

I want to insert `id: 'some_id'` at the beginning of `response`.
I have tried this, but it doesn't feel good to iterate over it:

```
new_response = { id: 'some id' }
response.keys.reverse.each {|key| new_response[key] = response[key] }
```

Basically, I need a similar feature like [Ruby Array's `unshift`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-unshift).

```
irb(main):042:0> arr = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):043:0> arr.unshift(5)
=> [5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: By definition, hashes are unordered. Therefore, the order of a hash cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: @zeantsoi: they're ordered in ruby since 1.9

Comment: @sawa: Updated now. I forgot single quote for value of 'bb'.

Comment: @Denis, while this may be true, in practice, hashes/dictionaries/key-value pairs are unordered across languages for a variety of good reasons. In general, if order needs to be guaranteed, an array/list is far more reliable of a construct.

Comment: @zeantsoi: But that is irrelevant, because in recent ruby versions, a hash is not a dictionary by the conventional definition; it merely masquerades as one.

Comment: @Denis, interesting... care to explain?

Comment: @zeantsoi: there's nothing to explain beyond what was already said... In addition to being a traditional key/value store, ruby hashes also maintain their list of keys as an ordered set. It looks and quacks like a dictionary, but it is not a dictionary in the usual sense.

Comment: Hashes are not "ordered" in the traditional sense, where the key/value-pairs would be sorted automatically. A Hash in Ruby *ONLY* is ordered in the sense that the key/values are maintained in their insertion order. `{'b' => 1, 'a' => 2} # => {"b"=>1, "a"=>2}` It if was "ordered" in any other sense the key/value pairs would change positions.

Comment: @theTinMan, this explanation makes sense and appears consistent with the behavior of Ruby hashes. I maintain that hashes are __not__ an _explicitly_ ordered set, and are therefore more akin to a dictionary than an ordered key-value set.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
response = {aa: 'aaa', bb: 'bbb'}
new_response = {new: 'new_value'}.merge(response)
# => {:new=>"new_value", :aa=>"aaa", :bb=>"bbb"}
```

Comment: Be careful, before ruby 1.9 hashes are not ordered

Comment: response = { aa: 'aaa', bb: 'bbb', cc: 'cc' }
    response.merge(cc: 'ccc')

will result in 

    { aa: 'aaa', bb: 'bbb', cc: 'ccc' }

if you do

    { cc: 'ccc' }.merge response

then the return value will be

    { cc: 'cc', aa: 'aaa', bb: 'bbb' }

this could be an expected return value of `response.unshift(cc: 'ccc')`(if there is such a method)?

If the expected return value should be `{ cc: 'ccc', aa: 'aaa', bb: 'bbb' }`, then what would be the answer?

Comment: If using ActiveSupport, this could be written as `new_response = response.reverse_merge(new: 'new_value')`

Comment: in complexity, it is O(n). but usually, we expect insert a key to hash is O(1)?

Answer (score 3):

Try converting it to an array and back:

```
Hash[hash.to_a.unshift([k, v])]
```

Comment: This is especially useful when altering subsets of a bigger hash.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
response.inject({:new=>"new_value"}) { |h,(k,v)| h[k]=v; h }
```

or like @sawa

Answer (score 0):

This is useful for me, because I want "timestamp" to be within the first 128 characters of the json for Splunk to read it, so I wanted to reorder the hash key to ensure timestamp is always at the beginning when converting `to_json`. Since log lines will be printed very often, I wanted to ensure the fastest, checking different combinations:

Used the following code to figure out which solution is fastest:

```rb
require 'securerandom'
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/reverse_merge'
require 'fruity'

SMALL_HASH = { aa: 'aaa', bb: 'bbb' }.freeze
BIG_HASH = 10_000.times.each_with_object({}) do |_, obj|
  obj[SecureRandom.alphanumeric(6).to_sym] = SecureRandom.alphanumeric(128)
end; nil

puts "Running on #{RUBY_VERSION}"
# Running on 2.6.9

compare do
  _small_merge { { new: 'new_value' }.merge(SMALL_HASH) }
  _small_reverse_merge { SMALL_HASH.reverse_merge(new: 'new_value') }
  _small_unshift { Hash[SMALL_HASH.to_a.unshift([:new, 'new_value'])] }
end

# Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# _small_merge is faster than _small_reverse_merge by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
# _small_reverse_merge is faster than _small_unshift by 1.9x ± 0.1

compare(magnify: 1_000) do
  _big_merge { { new: 'new_value' }.merge(BIG_HASH) }
  _big_reverse_merge { BIG_HASH.reverse_merge(new: 'new_value') }
  _big_unshift { Hash[BIG_HASH.to_a.unshift([:new, 'new_value'])] }
end

# Running each test 1000 times.
# _big_reverse_merge is similar to _big_merge
# _big_merge is faster than _big_unshift by 2x ± 0.1
```

So I would recommend using the following strategy

```rb
{ new: 'new_value' }.merge(aa: 'aaa', bb: 'bbb')
```